# Android: fixed position Toolbar

Tags: java, android, android-layout

That's my `MainActivity` xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".views.activities.MainActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/location_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/main_toolbar"
        android:name="com.myapp.views.fragments.mainActivity.LocationSearchFragment"
        android:tag="fragment_location_search"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_location_search"
        class="com.myapp.views.fragments.mainActivity.LocationSearchFragment" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/restaurants_list_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/location_fragment"
        android:name="com.myapp.views.fragments.mainActivity.RestaurantFragment"
        android:tag="fragment_restaurant_list"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_restaurant_list"
        class="com.myapp.views.fragments.mainActivity.RestaurantFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

When some event occurs (search is completed and there's data to display) I'd like to slide up `location_fragment` and `restaurants_list_fragment` but preserve the position of my custom toolbar. Code creating the animation looks as follows:

```
public void onRestaurantsSearchCompleted(RestaurantSearchCompleted evt) {   
    View locationView = findViewById(R.id.location_fragment);
    View restaurantsView = findViewById(R.id.restaurants_list_fragment);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams restaurantsLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(restaurantsView.getWidth(), Defaults.restaurantsFragmentHeightAfterAnimation);
    float slideUp = -Defaults.locationFragmentHiddenPartHeight;

    locationView.animate()
            .translationYBy(slideUp);
    restaurantsView.animate()
            .translationYBy(slideUp);
    restaurantsView.setLayoutParams(restaurantsLayoutParams);
}
```

The thing I'm struggling with right now is that the animation slides up also my custom toolbar. How to prevent that from happening?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly i would suggest you use CoordinatorLayout and place your toolbar inside it. [This](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/scrolling-techniques-for-material-design--cms-24435) is one of the most helpful resource that i found when i was looking to achieve something similar i hope it helps.

Comment: I didn't accept your answer because it didn't solve my problem. I have to programatically scroll the search panel up when some event occurs. Not when the user scrolls the list down. However I did give you the upvote because the link you attached will be very useful to me in some other scenarios.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Really appreciate it.